# Pom.xml cannot find artifact from m2 local repository

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I have created two projects using Spring Initializr: `message-spring-boot-starter` and `message-app`.

With the command `mvn clean install` I builded the artifact of the project `message-spring-boot-starter` and it appeared in the local m2 repository "com.message-starter"

Pom.xml of message-spring-boot-starter:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.message-starter</groupId>
    <artifactId>message-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>message-spring-boot-starter</name>
    <description>message-spring-boot-starter</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Pom.xml of message-app:

```
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>message-app</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>message-app</name>
    <description>message-app</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.message-starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>message-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I end up with an error: `Could not find artifact com.message-starter:message-spring-boot-starter:jar:unknown in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)`

I want to add `message-spring-boot-starter` to the dependency of `message-app` project but I get this error every time.

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it

Answer (score 3):

You need a `version` tag for your dependency which specifies the version of the artifact you are trying to pull.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.message-starter</groupId>
            <artifactId>message-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: While this will fix the issue, I would - for a multi-module setup - recommend to create a [`BOM` module](https://info.michael-simons.eu/2019/08/22/whats-a-bill-of-material-bom-file/) to manage dependencies in a central location.